# API controller action getting null value after Ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

I am getting post as null in My API controller Action GetVoteScores. Where i went wrong?. If any one need more code to check i will give it.

This is my API controller Action

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("GetVoteScores")]
    public string GetVoteScores(int id, int UserId, int IsUpVote,Post post)
    {
        return "1";
    }
```

This is my WebApI.config file

```
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "MyRoute",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/GetVoteScores/{id}/{UserId}/{IsUpVote}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, UserId = RouteParameter.Optional, IsUpVote = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

And finally my Ajax call look like

```
   var post = new Post();
    post.PostId = self.PostId;
    post.PostedBy = self.PostedBy;

    return $.ajax({
        url: postApiUrl + "GetVoteScores/" + self.PostId + "/1/0",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        data: ko.toJSON(post)
    })
```

Comment: How is `Post` looks like?

Comment: Mu URL looks like http://localhost:1268/api/WallPost/GetVoteScores/1/1/0?{%22PostId%22:1,%22Message%22:%22Sample%20Text%22,%22PostedBy%22:1,%22PostedByName%22:%22Nidhin%22,%22PostedByAvatar%22:%22/Images/profileimages/user.png%22,%22PostedDate%22:null,%22VoteScore%22:5,%22PostComments%22:[],%22PostDateFormat%22:%22%22}&_=1415262533319

Comment: You need to change `type` to `POST` instead of `GET`.

Comment: haim770 i changed it to type post. But my API controller have another function which named "PostPost". Now the call is going to that function not to GetVoteScores

Comment: Change `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]` to `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` as well.

Comment: Yes i changed it already. Do i need to change my function name from GetVoteScores to PostVoteScore. Is there is any relation with function name in API calls?

Comment: You aren't supposed to send complex data types (usually as JSON) to `GET` actions. If you only need to pass `PostId` and `PostedBy`, try to attach it to the Query-string as well.

Comment: Ok but i need to send my "post" object too.